# Regex for accepting given HTML

Tags: regex

I am looking for a Regex, for the following case:

I have a string which I have to validate so plain text and the following HTML is allowed:
h3, h4, h5, h6, span, b,  blockquote,  br,  cite,  code,  dd,  dl,  dt,  em,  i,  li,  ol,  p,  pre,  q,  small,  strike,  strong,  sub,  sup,  u,  ul,   ol

Java is the language I am programming.
Could you guys help me to write this Regular expression? Or is there any regex generator?

Comment: Regex for which programming language? One regex tester is https://regex101.com/, But for html you need a [sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization), as there is almost no regex due to the language structure, who can handle all.

Comment: @Myonara  I need the regex for java

Comment: searching for "regex java tester" shows https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html .

Answer (score 0):

As regex is not working for complex html cases, I stick with HTML sanitizer. For java I propose the [OWASP-Sanitizer Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project#tab=Main).